# How do I extract the elements of the Request Initiator Chain (as seen in the Network tab) via a CDP session in Playwright (JavaScript)?

Tags: google-chrome-devtools, httprequest, puppeteer, playwright, chrome-devtools-protocol

[Screenshot of Request Initiator Chain from Dev Tools Network Tab (Chromium Browser)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0SyMn.png)

Take this particular request: *"https://uk-script.dotmetrics.net/hit.gif?id=13934&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.bbc.com%2Fweather%2F1264527&dom=www.bbc.com&r=1686291576433&pvs=1&pvid=f4aaa4fd-2def-4a70-ab77-c4e11e570388&c=true&tzOffset=-330&doorUrl=http%3a%2f%2fuk-script.dotmetrics.net%2fdoor.js%3fd%3dwww.bbc.com%26t%3dweathergnl"*

We see in the Request Initiator Chain that the immediate parent to this request has the URL: *"https://uk-script.dotmetrics.net/door.js?d=www.bbc.com&t=weathergnl"*

This is the information that I want to extract.

Here's what I've tried. I used Playwright to open a CDP session and intercept Network calls. For each intercepted Network call, I extracted the Network.Initiator object.

```js
const { chromium } = require('playwright');

(async () => {
  // Launch browser with headless set to false
  const browser = await chromium.launch({ headless: false });
  let cnt = 1;

  // Create a new context with CDP enabled
  const context = await browser.newContext({
    devtools: true,
  });

  // Create a new page
  const page = await context.newPage();

  // Enable the CDP session
  const client = await page.context().newCDPSession(page);

  // Enable network interception
  await client.send('Network.enable');

  // Listen for network requests
  client.on('Network.requestWillBeSent', (event) => {
    console.log("::::::::::Network Call "+ cnt +"::::::::::");
    console.log('Request URL: ', event.request.url);
    console.log('\nInitiator: ', event.initiator);
    // console.log('\nReferer URL: ', event.request.headers);
    console.log("\n");
    cnt++;
  });

  // Navigate to the website
  await page.goto('https://www.bbc.com/weather/1264527');

  // Perform any further actions using the CDP session if needed
  // For example, you can use client.send() to interact with the CDP API.
  // Scroll down the page bit by bit
  const SCROLL_AMOUNT = 250; // Adjust the scroll amount as needed
  const pageHeight = await page.evaluate(() => document.documentElement.scrollHeight);

  let currentScroll = 0;
  while (currentScroll < pageHeight) {
    await page.evaluate((scrollAmount) => {
      window.scrollBy(0, scrollAmount);
    }, SCROLL_AMOUNT);
    currentScroll += SCROLL_AMOUNT;
    await page.waitForTimeout(500); // Adjust the timeout as needed
  }
  // Close the browser
  await browser.close();
})();
```

This is the result I'm getting for the same request from the image above:
[My result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S4Z9c.png)

Why is this Initiator URL different from the one seen in the browser Dev Tools window. Is there any other way I can get the exact initiator as seen in the request initiator chain?

Answer (score 0):

The initiator property merely shows the *immediate* initiator of the request, not the entire tree. In order to get the tree hierarchy shown by Chrome DevTools, you will need to build the tree yourself.

Some things to keep in mind from my own experience:

- an initiator will not always be provided
- network events may be sent out of order, ie, a child request may arrive before its parent

The code to build this tree is somewhere in the Chromium source code, but might not have the same constraints as I mentioned above, so may not be all that useful. Good luck!